# microsoft excel scatter chart does not display data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I am trying to create a sctter chart in MS Excel 2013.  I insert the chart, then I click "select data".  (I know I'm doing this backwards from the way it is usually explained, but I need to do it this way for reasons I won't take the time to go into.  And this certainly used to work in older versions of Excel.)  In the "Select Data Source" window that opens up, I give the data ranges for the x values and the y values.  Then I click "OK" and .... the chart remains completely blank.  Any way to convince it to display the data?  Thanks.

Comment: quite difficult to say anything based on your description:(.. Please try the common order too, to see whether that works? Can you insert another type of chart on the same data? Also please post some screenshots how your data and chart looks like.

Comment: This question is missing a lot of detail we need to be able to help. **BUT** maybe this is an easy solution. Is the workbook set to auto calculate? If not, you need to press F9 to make it update with the changes.